# get output element by element when input a list

Tags: python, list, output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCOS3.jpg)I want to enter numbers separated by spaces as input. Store the numbers in a list and get the elements by elements in that list as output.

This was my code.

```
lst = input()
test_list =[]

for ele in lst.split():
    n_int = int(ele)
    test_list.append(n_int)

for i in range(len(test_list)):
    print(i)
```

When I enter a input like `4 7 9`, I expect an output like this.
`4 7 9`
But I get this output
`0 1 2`

Comment: You are printing the index of the item, not the actual item. To do this you could print `test_list[i]` or just use the line `for i in test_list` rather than `for i in range(len(test_list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `range()` function which helps to go index by index in list if you wanted to go item by item you don't need to use `range()` you can simply access items by iterating see the below code..

```
for i in test_list:
    print(i)
```

You can also do with `range()` function simple accessing list by index and print..

```
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    print(test_list[i])
```

The above 2 solutions will give output

```
3
7
9
```

If you wanted in same line like `3 7 9` you can use `end` in print

```
print(i,end=" ")    or    print(test_list[i],end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

fist let's dissect your code flow:-

```
test_list = ["4", "7", "9"]
```

Then: `len(test_list)` is `3`

So

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

This will result in:-

```
0 
1
2
```

You could get your printed desired output with:-

```
for ele in lst.split():
    n_int = int(ele)
    test_list.append(n_int)
    print(ele)
```

where `print(ele)` will print each number in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last lines:

try this:

```
print(test_list[i])
```

or this will work too:

```
for i in test_list:
    print(i)
```